# AZ CLI: how to add tags when creating SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-cli

How to add tags when creating SQL server resource, usually "--tags env:prod" works with other resources, but not with SQL server.

az sql server create --name $SQLName --resource-group $resourceGroup --tags env:prod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks the `az sql server create` does not have the built-in `--tags` parameter, see official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-server-create).

If you want to add tags to the sql server, you could use the [`az sql server update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-update) after creating the server, if the tag name `env` already exists, it will overwrite the value.

**Sample**:

```
az sql server update -n 'sqlserver-name' -g 'group-name' --set tags.env=prod
```

[image]

Comment: ...update will work when tags are nor required, but it does not help when our admin on corporate level has configured Azure (using a policy) to require tags to be provided when resources are created.